# Mean Value Theorem applied on $x^t$

Tags: calculus, functions

I am trying to prove that when Mean Value Theorem is applied on function $f(x)=x^t$ where $t\geq 2$ on interval $[a,b]$ with $0 < a < b$, then the point $c$ given by the theorem, i.e. such $c$ satisfying

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \text{ for } a < c < b,$$

also satisfies

$$c \geq \frac{a+b}{2}.$$

In other words $c$ is past midpoint of the interval $[a,b]$, closer to the point $b$.

It is supposed to be obvious (I found this statement without proof), but I don't see how it follows. I have tried several different approaches, but none of them lead me anywhere.

I wonder if this is more general result, perhaps something related to the convex functions?

Comment: Are you sure it is true. What if $t=1$?

Comment: There is the condition $t \geq 2$ stated. For $t=1$ this does not really work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $t>2$, $x^{t-1}$ is convex and we can apply Jensen's inequality.
$$
c^{t-1}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bx^{t-1}\,dx\ge\Bigl(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bx\,dx\Bigr)^{t-1}=\Bigl(\frac{a+b}{2}\Bigr)^{t-1}.
$$

Comment: Are beginning Calculus students expected to know Jensen's?

Comment: Not in Spain were I live, neither in EEUU, were I got my Phd. But the question seems to me above Calculus level.

Comment: Very nice solution! I guess i am going to read something about Jensen's inequality. Thank you.